# Android app doesn't use system proxy

Tags: android, android-emulator, proxy, fiddler, nexus-7

I have developed a simple android app which uses a Video View to play a video on the app. I want to check the requests made by it.

I'm running this project from Intellij jetbrains on my Nexus 7 device. I have configured Fiddler to accept connections from remote machines; I have also set up the proxy on my Nexus 7 device as well. Now when I launch any app that connects to the net from my Nexus 7, I see the HTTP requests it makes on fiddler running on my lap. However, I do not see any requests when I launch my app and even when it starts playing the video. 
Is this because I have not configured my app to use the system proxy? Can anyone point me on how to do this? Do I do this via code or any setting?